# In DevExpress Grid, how can we change color code of values in bold in summary section after grouping? Please refer snap

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress-gridcontrol

After GROUP BY, which method can be used for color coding of summary in grid view? 
I am able to make changes in color code for value under grid at specific level of record, but for cumulative value, I am having difficulties.

[Link for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsDgP.png)

Please find link for image and highlighted part in blue for timestamps for Visit Count row, which need to be color coded.

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender,
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.DataColumn.FieldName != "Budget") return;
    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue) < 100000)
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Definitely show your code.  DevExpress have some complex methods but they work very well..  Also, please make more question more clear....See this link https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115548/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Appearance-and-Conditional-Formatting

Answer (score 0):

This might help you....

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlFooterCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableFooterCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column is GridViewDataColumn  )((GridViewDataColumn)e.Column).FieldName == "Freight")
            {
                e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                e.Cell.Font.Bold = true;
            }
}
```